# Riley Rebus is a calm man

Tags: knowledge, rebus

[image]

Prefix + Infix + Suffix

I will post hints as time goes on.

Hint 1:

> You will have to think more abstractly than what is **literally** in the pictures.

Hint 2:

> Its not about the stones. Its about the abstract idea that is associated with them.

Hint 3:

> EK

Hint 4:

> The Stones represent an act often performed by mindful people.

Hint 5:

> **XXX**x  **X**x  **XXXX**x

Comment: Decided to make on of the Riley Rebus, I see. Nice puzzle mate :D

Comment: I loved it! Hope you dont mind!

Comment: Nah, I'm glad someone made another of this :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Could the answer be

> **STACK EXCHANGE**?

Prefix:

> **STACK** because the Zen stones are being **stacked**.

Infix:

> **EX**. As the element is an **isotope** of Hydrogen (H), it is literally **ex**-Hydrogen.

Suffix:

> **CHANGE**. The infinite series **changes** sign (positive, negative, positive, negative, ...)

---

**Title:**

`Riley Rebus is a calm man`

> The Zen stones refer to **calmness**.

> "Tritium" sounds like **tranquility**.

> "Equation" sounds like **equable**.

$$$$

**Hints:**

1. `You will have to think more abstractly than what is literally in the pictures.`

> Most of the pictures refer to how they **sound** like (and the prefix has quite nothing to do with Zen stones).

2. `It's not about the stones; It's about the abstract idea that is associated with them.`

> True. They are **stacked**.

3. `EK`

> What does K "loo**k** li**k**e"? It looks like an **X**. EK looks like **EX**. Also, the phrase "Stack Exchange" has **EK** in it, but backwards (Stac**k** **E**xchange).

4. `The Stones represent an act often performed by mindful people.`

> To be mindful means to be aware, and you are aware of more of your surroundings if it is **neat** and **organised**. Stacking objects (like books) often creates such a surrounding. "Stacking" also describes an **act**ion that of which can be performed.

5. `XXXx Xx XXXXx`

> STACK E**X**CHANGE

Comment: this is a nice answer, hoping this would be it.

Comment: @ShahriarMahmudSajid Yeah, me too :P

Comment: I actually thought of this answer yesterday because of the stones, but couldn't explain the rest. Good to see someone who can explain this :). Let's hope it is correct.

Comment: WOW! GOOD JOB :D

Comment: @Dylan Hahah, thanks man! It was a really nice and fun Riley Rebus :D

Answer (score 8):

Partial:

For the suffix:

> With a little help from [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20from%200%20to%20infinity%20((-1)%5En%20*%20(x%5E(2n%2B1))%2F((2n%2B1)!))) I found that the above equation is actually $\sin(x)$. So I guess the suffix = ***sin***. Or it could be something like ***nth*** or ***ith*** because the equation is an infinite sum and nth or ith referrs to nth element.

For the infix:

> The tritium is one of the hydrogen's isotopes. I would place my bet on iso. So infix = ***iso***.

For the prefix:

> The image depicts zen stones; based on the hints it must be something to do with ***soul*** or ***harmony***.

After the latest hints, etc and also considering the puzzle title I'm totally confused. Could it be something like:

> Harmonising? It starts with har(mony) - that picture sure looks peaceful. It contains (sort of) sin in the end. But where is the relation to tritium and to the girl from the title?

Comment: Your on to something!

Comment: Ill post this as a hint, While they are called zen stones. They can often have another name.

Comment: These specific stone formation would go by the name ROT13: "Fuvagnv" AFAIK. Don't see where that helps, though.

Comment: These are called shintai stones in Japanese if that's any help.

Comment: @stackreader approach those stones as if you were a "layperson" who had no knowledge of their actual names.

Comment: @Dylan Then I would say STACKed stones

Comment: Stacked stones can also be a CAIRN (ie Karen?) but I might be off.

Comment: I'm thinking skipping stones, i.e. skip?